# Html date format change to Month date Year

Tags: html, datepicker

Is it possible to change the datepicker input format to month name date and year (example January 13 2019. Now it is mm/dd/yyyy (US) format? Present Code is

```
<label>
  <input type="date" name="lastBeginDate" id="lastBeginDate" required=""> Pick a Date
</label>
```

Output: 
[image]

Comment: what datepicker we are talking about here? bootstrap datepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using jquery UI Datepicker,

The format should be `MM d, y`

Read the doc here https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

Comment: now its return like this..>  January 31, 2019 i have to convert it like 2019-01-01 can you help with this.?

Comment: there is 2 option format in jquery datepicker, altField, and altFormat, you are talking about altField here, read this doc here  http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField

Answer (score 0):

This function will do that for you

```
function formatDate(date){
    date = new Date(date)
    let months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","July","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
    return `${months[date.getMonth()]} ${date.getDate()} ${date.getFullYear()}`
}
```

Update:
Here is second conversion you need

```
function formatDate(date){
    date = new Date(date)
    return `${date.getFullYear()}-${(date.getMonth() < 10) ? 0:''}${date.getMonth()}-${(date.getDay() < 10) ? 0:''}${date.getDay()}`
}
```

Comment: it works for the date picker you gave in html. Tell me what if format of your datepicker value

Comment: i got a solution. but now its return like this..> January 31, 2019 now i have to convert it like 2019-01-01 can you help with this.?